# How to automatically save sessions with multiple windows in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I've used primarily Firefox's built-in session management until recently. Now my needs have become more sophisticated. What I want is to be able to have two windows, one with a fixed set of tabs (approximately five) and the other with "automatic save".

That is, when I start Firefox, I want one window to open with my five tabs, and another to open with whatever I had when I shut down Firefox. I've installed "Session Manager", but I can't seem to get it to do what I want. It will save one window, but when I close one window, it removes that one from the session.

How do I do this with either Session Manager or another plugin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just make sure *"Tools > Options > Main > Startup > When Firefox starts > show my windows and tabs from last time"* is selected and that you close Firefox from *"File > Exit"* so you close all windows. If you close Firefox windows separately Firefox will only bring back the last closed window.

This was my set-up, but now I just use one window, together with the FaviconizeTab addon to strip the titles from all tabs, and leave the permanent tabs at the leftmost positions. This way, I don't have to switch between Firefox windows.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! Firefox has built-in session management that will do what I need, but all session managers work the same way. When you close FF by closing each window individually, they remove that window from the session. I did not realize that choosing File->Exit would shut down FF completely. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It should work with the [**Tab Mix Plus**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122) add-on. It comes with its own session manager.

> **Tab Mix Plus (TMP)** is a very popular
>   extension for the Mozilla Firefox
>   browser that enhances Firefox's tab
>   browsing capabilities. It includes
>   such features as duplicating tabs,
>   controlling tab focus, tab clicking
>   options, undo closed tabs and windows,
>   plus much more. *It also includes a
>   full-featured Session Manager with
>   crash recovery that can save and
>   restore combinations of opened tabs
>   and windows*.

I think that, in the windows with the predefined set of tabs, you'd have to use the command "Protect tab" (or "Freeze" or "Lock", by right-click on the tab) for the tab you want to keep.

> **Protected tab**: A tab that is prevented
>   from closing. You can load other sites
>   in the tab and browse to other URLs in
>   the tab. Notice that the close button
>   is missing from the right side of the
>   tab, so you cannot close the tab. If
>   you try to close Firefox, you will get
>   a warning message about closing the
>   protected tab.
>
> **Locked tab**: A tab that is prevented
>   from navigating to another page or
>   URL. Your tab is locked on the current
>   page or URL. Nothing new can load in
>   the tab, but you can refresh the same
>   page. All links will open in a new tab
>   (link, history, bookmark, etc.).
>   Notice that the close button is
>   available, so you can close a locked
>   tab.
>
> **Frozen tab**: A tab that is both locked
>   and protected. It will not close and
>   nothing new can be loaded in it. You
>   will not be able to navigate away from
>   the current page. All links will open
>   in a new tab (link, history, bookmark,
>   etc.) Notice that the close button is
>   missing from the right side of the
>   tab, so you cannot close the tab. If
>   you try to close Firefox, you will get
>   a warning message about closing the
>   protected tab.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on here that you can use:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-my-tabs/

You can quickly recover the tabs which are automatically saved as a [.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text) file.

You can then use for example http://linkopener.com to open them all

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a session manager add-on + [PermaTabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7816) would get you there. Only thing might be that it would open the permanent tabs plus your last session in the same window -- I don't know, you'd have to check it out.

Comment: I'm not sure how PermaTabs would really help. I can already save the tabs I want in a bookmark folder, then "Open All in Tabs". This is my current approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you set "Tools > Options > Main > Startup > When Firefox starts > Show my windows and tabs from last time". There is also an add-on that adds a toolbar button to "Exit Firefox" to close and save all windows.

Comment: `Show my windows and tabs from last time` option is not found on Firefox 72.